# удаление дубликатов одновременно из двух ArrayList

Tags: java, коллекции, arraylist

есть два списка:
1. (1,2,3,4)
2. (2,3,4,5)
нужно удалить у обоих списках все дубликаты,что бы вывод на экран имел вид всего лишь двух цифр-1 и 5,по логике.Мои попытки не приносят успех,выручайте)

```
public class ArrayListTwo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayOne = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    arrayOne.add(1);
    arrayOne.add(2);
    arrayOne.add(3);
    arrayOne.add(4);

    ArrayList<Integer> arrayTwo = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    arrayTwo.add(2);
    arrayTwo.add(3);
    arrayTwo.add(4);
    arrayTwo.add(5);

    List<Integer> sum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    sum.addAll(arrayOne);
    sum.addAll(arrayTwo);
    System.out.println(sum);
    System.out.println("before");

    for (int x = 0; x < sum.size(); x++) {
       for (int y = 0; y < sum.size(); y++) {
    if (sum.get(x) == sum.get(y)) {
    sum.remove(y);


    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    }
    }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int y = x + 1; y < sum.size(); y++) {
  if (sum.get(x) == sum.get(y)) {
    sum.remove(y);
    y--;
    y--;
    sum.remove(x);
    x--;
  }
}
```

Comment: получается [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],а надо [1,5],что бы все числа которые повторяются были удалены полностью.Необходимо,что бы выводились те цифры которых нет в первом и во втором списке.Мой код скорее всего не подходит.

Comment: спасибо!супер!)

Answer (score 1):

```
sum.stream()
        .filter(a -> !(arrayOne.contains(a) && arrayTwo.contains(a)))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: это С++?я новичок еще в программировании,по этому мне к сожалению не понятна ваша запись(

Comment: все равно спасибо,есть от чего отталкиваться,вижу знакомые слова)

Comment: Просто вставь это вместо этой части своего кода
  for (int x = 0; x < sum.size(); x++) {
       for (int y = 0; y < sum.size(); y++) {
    if (sum.get(x) == sum.get(y)) {
    sum.remove(y);


    }
    System.out.println(sum);

Вся логика в этой строчке: a->!(arrayOne.contains(a) && arrayTwo.contains(a)). Элемент не должен повторяться в двух коллекциях

Comment: спасибо большое!)то что нужно!

Comment: а не могли бы написать пожалуйста по примитивному,в духе моего кода?что бы разобраться мог лучше,для меня пока что это не со всем легко

Comment: вы использовали лямбду функцию?верно?поправьте если что)мне просто любопытно

Comment: @PeteShevchenko это Stream API.

Comment: я понял,спасибо большое)